# Finding percent weight

Tags: stoichiometry

I have a mixture of $\ce{NO2(g)}$ and $\ce{N2O4(g)}$ at $63\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $750\ \mathrm{mmHg}$. I need to find the weight percent of the first compound. Density $d=1.98\ \mathrm{g/L}$.

I assumed that we have $M=aM_1+bM_2$ where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the molar masses of the first and second compound. I know that $m=nM$ so the weight percent would be $$\frac{m_1}{m}\cdot100\ \%=\frac{aM_1}{aM_1+bM_2}\cdot100\ \%$$
My problem lies in finding the coefficients. Can someone give a hint please?

Comment: You need to know the equilibrium constant for this temperature, and then use a similar approach as shown here: [How can I calculate the percentage of dissociated dinitrogen tetroxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65331/how-can-i-calculate-the-percentage-of-dissociated-dinitrogen-tetroxide)

Comment: @andselisk I still haven't learnt that, so the question doesn't require that approach. thank you though :)

Comment: There is an equilibrium between both components which dictates the fraction of each, and without $K_p$ I doubt you'll be able to do much.

Comment: but seriously, we are supposed to do this without using the equilibrium.

Comment: Personally, I don't see how this could be done with the data you posted. Could you please add a source for this problem?

Comment: From my university professor. Since this is leading nowhere.. In the solution he uses mole fractions $X$. He takes the molar mass found as an average molar mass, so that $M=XM_1+(1-X)M_2$ and then finds $X$ using given data. Then he considers mass fractions and gets $\%w=\frac{XM_1}{XM_1+(1-X)M_2}*100\%$

Comment: I don't understand this, however, $X$ is dimensionless, $XM_1$ makes no sense to me. Or maybe by weight percentage he means molar mass not mass?

Comment: There is no given average molar mass of the mixture, so you stuck with one equation and two unknowns, and in order to use the second equation, you also need to find molar fraction $x_1$ (or $X$, according to your notations), which is normally done using $K_p.$ From the dimensional analysis everything looks fine, I don't understand why $x_1M_1$ doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: We can find the actual molar mass with the density formula involving pressure and temperature, then consider it as the average molar mass. I know understand when I look at the full equation: the total number of moles will cancel each other from nominator and denominator and we will end up with (implicitly, since we won't actually be simplifying) $\frac {XM_1}{XM_1+(1-X)M_2}=\frac {n_1M_1}{n_1M_1+n_2M_2}=m_1/m$.

Comment: I assume you mean ideal gas law $\bar{M} = \frac{ρRT}{p}$ ($\bar{M}$ is the average molar mass), but there is no given density of gaseous mixture $ρ$ either. So how is this going to be helpful here?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include it. It is $1.98\,g/L$.

Comment: Why do we consider that as average molar mass, though? Doesn't it give the actual one of the system?

Comment: Well, now you know how to solve this, too bad you didn't show the complete data from problem from the beginning as this would save time. What do you mean by "*actual one*"? $\bar{M}$ *is* the actual average molar mass of the mixture.

Comment: I meant the real not average.

Comment: The average one is also *very real*. At this point I suggest you edit the missing density into the question, and you can also post an answer. Lengthy comments are going to be purged (or moved to the chat by the system or us mods) in a matter of hours/days.

Comment: Please don't use number of moles, this is an ancient term dating back before a proper definition of amount of substance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the average molar mass with the density formula involving pressure and temperature $\overline M=\frac{\rho TR}{p}$.

We also know that, in this case, $\overline M=\frac{n_1M_1+n_2M_2}{n_1+n_2}$. Since we only "care" about $M_1$ we can write the average molar mass as $\overline M=\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}M_1+(1-\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2})M_2$ and then find $\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$.
$$\frac{\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}M_1}{\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}M_1+(1-\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2})M_2}^{(*)}=\frac{\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}M_1}{\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}M_1+\frac{n_2}{n_1+n_2}M_2}=\frac{n_1M_1}{n_1M_1+n_2M_2}=\frac{m_1}{m_{total}}$$
Compute $(*)\cdot100\%$. The development of the fraction was to show why it works.

Another possible solution is this :
$$\%w_{m_1}=\frac{m_1}{\rho V}*100\%\Leftrightarrow m_1=\%w_{m_1}\rho V/100\%$$
$$\%w_{m_2}=\frac{m_2}{\rho V}*100\%=100\%-\%w_{m_1}\Leftrightarrow m_2=(100\%-\%w_{m_1})\rho V/100\%$$
$$n=\frac{m_1}{M_1}+\frac{m_2}{M_2}=\frac{\rho V}{100\%}\left(\frac{\%w_{m_1}}{M_1}+\frac{100\%-\%w_{m_1}}{M_2}\right)=\frac{PV}{RT}$$